# Libpdf_php complaining about non thread safe binaries

Tags: macos, pdf, php, libraries, mamp

I installed libpdf_php on MAMP v2.0 and after restarting Apache I get following error:

```
[11-Jan-2013 11:48:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdf: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20100525,TS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20100525,NTS
These options need to match
```

This results of course in PHP not loading that module. For some reasons I cannot change the php installation to thread safe, and I couldn't find any downloads of the library in NTS.

How to get the library to work? Any ideas will be welcomed!